# QGIS Rasters - Filling no data cells

Tags: qgis, raster

When making a sum between two raster layers, for every cell, if one of the two cells have no data in that cell, the opeartion is not done in that cell, example:

In QGIS raster calculator I do:

[image]

Plus (+)

[image]

And I get:

[image]

The red circle in the middle is like cut in the result, QGIS it's not adding every pixel on each raster, it makes a kind of intersecction...

To try to avoid this, I need to fill every no-data cell in both raster layers with a 0 value. How can i do this in QGIS?

Comment: Have you tried using the **Fill nodata** tool from _Raster_ > _Analysis_ > _Fill nodata_?

Comment: Yes, I am not able to configure it to do what I need to...

Comment: Could you edit your question and paste the results of the gdalinfo() command, accessible under "Raster|Miscellaneous|Information..."?